# Why isnt localhost loading all the correct resources of my wordpress application?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, localhost, mamp

I am trying to copy down my web app from the internet to localhost on my machine for further development. The URL of my project is www.uniformlab.net. I am new to wordpress and this site is the biggest one that I have tried to copy.

I am using MAMP as my local server and have set up all the correct variables in getting the database set up. Some resources are loading and many are not, with a large download time.

This is a list of errors that are being thrown on runtime of the website. I don't think that these resources are being called from an absolute path.

I have set the `home` and `siteurl` settings in the DB to `locahost:80/UNIFORMLAB`

When I change the url to `localhost/uniformlab/wp-admin`, I am getting thrown `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` by the browser.

I have checked my htaccess file and it seems normal. This is what I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>



# END WordPress
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not too much info, but one thing is that the `home` and `siteurl` in WordPress have to be the full path to the WordPress directory.

You said that your URL is `http://localhost/uniformlab` but you changed the setting to `localhost`

Update again the `home` and `siteurl` to `http://localhost/uniformlab`

Comment: Made the change.. Still getting errors. Is there anywhere else in wordpress config files that a redirect could take place?